# excel macro for to call next cell value copied on the next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want such a macro when I run a macro it copies the cell value from sheet1 A3 and paste it into sheet2 A3 once it done when I again click on next button then A4 value copied and paste it on sheet2 A3 cell

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

Copy this to your module .

```
Dim i As Integer
Sub sample()

    If i = 0 Then
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("A3").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
    Else
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("A4").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
    End If
     i = i + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an iterator into a cell for example Sheet1 A1 = 3 then use that to select where you place your copied value

```
Sub sample()
    'This is your iterator
    x = Range("A1")
    Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") = Value
    Range("A1") = Range("A1") + 1
End Sub
```